# Where to put parameterised mapGetters (in computed or methods of component)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In vuex, I have this:

```
getByLessonId: state => _lessonId => {
  return state.entities.filter(e => e.lesson.id === _lessonId);
},
```

In component:

```
// using as a method...
...mapGetters("assignment", { getAssignmentsByLessonId: "getByLessonId" }),
```

Later in the code, since the mapping returns the function, I need to call it like this?

```
// load this lessons assignments...
this.assignments = this.getAssignmentsByLessonId()(this.id);

// this is what i started with
// this.$store.getters["assignment/getByLessonId"](this.id)
```

It works, just not sure if there is a better way to do this? Or should I put `mapGetters` in the computed properties of the component?

Answer (score 0):

Better put mapGetters (as long as mapState) in a `computed` section of a component. This is a recommended way to use several getters or props of a state because you have one place only to control getters and props in a component.

Comment: Why is it a bad thing to put mapgetters in methods of component instead of computed? I also want to pass argument to my getters.

Comment: I meant against direct getters calls or accessing state props. In case of placing `getters` in `methods` section you already mentioned that you have to use addtional `()` to get a real getter first (compare with calling these getters declared via `computed`).